# Enterprise Wireless 5GHz Deauth

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, kali-linux, sniffing, ssid

I am running blackbox pentests on an enterprise wireless setup. My area of attack consists of multiple APs that have both a 2.4GHz and a 5GHz radio.

I have successfully deauthenticated users from the 2.4GHz radio and they jumped to the 5GHz one.

The problem comes when I try to deauth them from the 5GHz radio. I expected that they would either jump back to the 2.4GHz radio or they would be temporary deauthed. But neither of those cases is happening.

When I run the deauth attack I constantly receive acknowledgments of the deauths (or ACKs) from both the targeted AP and the targeted victim's MAC address but the connection to the internet is still alive and no interference is noticed in the targeted machine.

Is this some kind of 5GHz protocol problem? Does the re-connection to the 5GHz radio happen too quickly? Is it backwards compatible (I mean, can the jump from 5 to 2.4 actually happen)?

Note: The tests are done correctly with the correct devices and tools (mdk3, aireplay and other custom made tools) in accordance with the requirements.

Comment: Are you *sure* you did the attack correctly? I ask because if you accidentally kept telling your deauth tool to use the AP's 2.4GHz BSSID (AP MAC address) instead of switching to its 5GHz BSSID, I could imagine the packets getting ACKed but discarded. By the way, is 802.11w in use on the 5GHz radio?

Comment: Yes, the attack is done correctly, the AP has 2 different BSSID's for the 2.4 and 5. I made sure to chose them correctly when I launch the tests. For the 5Ghz frequency attacks I used both my machine's embedded wireless driver that can support 2.4 and 5 and a TP-Link WDN3200 that also supports both of the frequencies. Also when I launched the attack I made sure to target the right channel, I have monitored the traffic while attacking and it keeps switching the target's power to 0 and back on -X but no effect on the internet connection. Just to clear things out.